# Key is inaccessible due to internal protection level (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm currently coding my first own app. I have an issue with a dictionary in Swift three where when I'm checking for a specific key it gives me the error 'Key is inaccessible due to internal protection level'

This is where I get the error

```
func handleEvent(cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState){
    guard let cell = cell as? CustomCell else {return}
    cell.eventView.isHidden = !workoutDictionary.contains { $0.key ==  formatter.string(from: cellState.date)}
}
```

And here is where I created the Dictionary

```
var workouts: [Workout] = []
var cardioWorkouts: [CardioWorkout] = []

var workoutDictionary : [[String : Any]] = []

func convertArrayToDictionaries(array: [Workout]) {
    for workout in array {
         let  dictionary = [
            "date" : convertDates(date: workout.workoutDate),
            "dayType" : workout.dayType!,
            "exercises" : workout.exercises,
            "duration" : workout.duration!,
        ] as [String : Any]
        workoutDictionary.append(dictionary)
    }
}

func convertCardioArrayToDictionaries(array: [CardioWorkout]) {
    for cardioWorkout in array {
         let  dictionary = [
            "date" : convertDates(date: cardioWorkout.workoutDate),
            "cardioType" : cardioWorkout.cardioType,
            "distance" : cardioWorkout.distance!,
            "duration" : cardioWorkout.duration!,
            ] as [String : Any]
        workoutDictionary.append(dictionary)
    }
}

func convertDates(date: Date) -> String{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let oldString = formatter.string(from: date)
    let date: Date? = formatter.date(from: oldString)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
    let string = formatter.string(from: date!)
    return string
}
```

Thanks for your Help!